# Mysql: Get no of records for todays date

Tags: mysql

I think this question may be answered earlier and I found one answer for it. Unfortunately, I am still getting the error.

I have a table which contains 5 records at the moment.

I am creating one query to get the records created by user on today.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalrecords 
FROM messages 
WHERE posted_by = 34 
and posted_on >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

This query is returning all 5 records. Actually only 2 records are created on today.

This is the format of `posted_on` field. `2020-06-14 15:23:02`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalrecords 
FROM messages 
WHERE posted_by = 34 
and posted_on = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

This is retuning 0 records.

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: When you change the `>=` to `=` you make the test much more specific. It will always be using the time as well as date the way you coded it, but when you make the test `=` then it is checking the Date and TIme in `CURRENT_DATE()` is exactly the same as the Date and Time in `posted_on`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So, in this case what exactly i need to do?

Comment: You might edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want any row with the specific date, ignoring the time part, try

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalrecords 
FROM messages 
WHERE posted_by = 34 
and DATE(posted_on) = DATE(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```